# Javascript switch statement using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, switch-statement

I'm attempting an exercise and can't quite understand where I'm going wrong.

I have a form where my postcode field will only validate if it meets the requirements of the regex specific to the state chosen.
I need to use a switch statement to determine what RegEx to use based on the state choice.

This is what I have so far:

```
function validPostCode() {
  var state = (document.getElementById("state").value);

  switch (state) {
    case "SA":
    var stateRegEx = /^5([0-9]{3})$/;
    break;
    case "NSW":
    var stateRegEx = /^2([0-9]{3})$/;
    break;
  }
  return stateRegEx.test(document.getElementById("postcode").value);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Is the code breaking?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function validPostCode() {
  var state = (document.getElementById("state").value);
  var stateRegEx;            // added here

  switch (state) {
    case "SA":
    stateRegEx = /^5([0-9]{3})$/;    // var removed
    break;
    case "NSW":
    stateRegEx = /^2([0-9]{3})$/;    // var removed
    break;
  }
  return stateRegEx.test(document.getElementById("postcode").value);
}
```